# AngularJS ng-model for a table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I have a table like in the picture. The user can make an entry anywhere in the table. My question now would be where to assign the user- entry. Do I have to make a variable for each cell in the controller or is there a better way?

[image: My Table]

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays for `ng-model`.

Create an array to keep all the stuff you need, and then loop over the array and create table rows and columns. And for each cell, use the corresponding data cell as the `ng-model` for the text box.

Take a look at this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lGY66zCeUXPuNSLBnweS?p=preview